# How to pass compile options to perl using plenv or perlbrew

Tags: perl, perlbrew, plenv

I have one machine that runs Windows 10 with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. It uses some kind of FUSE filesystem that has no proper hard link support.

Because of this, a typical [perl compilation fails](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/532). If I want to compile, I need to do:

```
echo "dont_use_nlink='define'" >> Policy.sh
./Configure -des
make
make install
```

What I'd ideally want is to be able to use either `perlbrew` or `plenv` to manage my perls and pass the `dont_use_nlink` parameter to any perl I build. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You could always just install the Perl into `"${PERLBREW_ROOT:-$HOME/perl5/perlbrew}/perls/$name/"` using your current method.

Comment: That's true. And then I could still use `perlbrew` to manage them. But I'd really prefer to also be able to install them using `plenv` or `perlbrew` as well. I can find how to pass options such as `-D usemymalloc` via perlbrew to `Configure` but I seem to be only able to set `dont_use_nlink` by using `Policy.sh`.

Comment: `-D` is for cpp defines, so not the way. I thought `-A` might be the way, but I failed to figure out how if so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, it looks like the [underlying issue in Win10 WSL is fixed](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/910#issuecomment-265257588), and will be (hopefully) released soon.

As MichielB pointed out, -A or -D seem like they should accomplish this, but it appears from some of my testing that perl's [Configure](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/Perl-Configure-0.07/lib/Perl/Configure.pm) doesn't honor `-A` or `-D` arguments when `-de` is also passed (see ["usage" in perl's metaconfig](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JHI/metaconfig-for-Perl-5.8.0/U.check/U/all/Options.U) for the significance of those args). Despite clearly seeing properly formed -A and -D flags in the args list of the generated config.sh, the dont_use_nlink never gets added.

As it happens, perlbrew passes those as the defaults unless you use the [special `PERLBREW_CONFIGURE_FLAGS` environment variable](https://github.com/gugod/App-perlbrew/blob/develop/perlbrew#L1547).

However, there is a workaround. You can use `PERLBREW_CONFIGURE_FLAGS` to use `-f` to pass our own configuration file. We can use the mostly-correct config.sh generated by a failed "perlbrew install" run, then tweak it and pass it in.

Steps:

1. Run a perlbrew install that will fail, eg:

`perlbrew install perl-5.24.0`

2. Copy the generated config.sh file somewhere for modification and reuse:

`cp /home/USERNAME/perl5/perlbrew/build/perl-5.24.0/config.sh ~/config_dont_use_nlink.sh`

3. Edit the file to and insert `dont_use_nlink='define'`. If you're being tidy and filing it alphabetically, it'll go between dlsrc and doubleinfbytes:

`dlsrc='dl_dlopen.xs'
dont_use_nlink='define'
doubleinfbytes='0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf0, 0x7f'`

4. Run perlbrew install, but set an environment variable that will cause "-f" to be passed through to the new perl's Configure script:

`PERLBREW_CONFIGURE_FLAGS="-de -f /home/USERNAME/config_dont_use_nlink.sh" perlbrew install perl-5.24.0`

That compiles for me on a mostly-clean WSL on Win10 build 14393, and has nearly all tests pass (with the remainder looking like stuff with WSL bugs already filed).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at Windows 10 or the new bash shell for Windows, so I don't know how compatible that new Windows bash environment is with perlbrew or plenv.

An alternative approach would be to leverage versions of portable [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).  A while back, David Farrell wrote berrybrew to mimic perlbrew on Windows using portable Strawberry Perl rather than compiling Perl from source code.  He wrote a [blog post](http://perltricks.com/article/119/2014/10/10/Hello-berrybrew--the-Strawberry-Perl-version-manager/) about it and put his stuff out on GitHub ([berrybrew](https://github.com/dnmfarrell/berrybrew)).  Later, Steve Bertrand wanted to add more functionality and eventually ended up forking the project.  You can read more about it on his [blog post](http://blogs.perl.org/users/steve_bertrand/2016/07/berrybrew-the-perlbrew-for-windows-rewritten-and-enhanced.html) and his forked project is out on GitHub (see [here](https://github.com/stevieb9/berrybrew)).

Unless you're needing/wanting to build Perl versions from source code, using berrybrew may provide you with the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is a possibility of running native Linux applications on Windows. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about - while I appreciate that I can also run StrawberryPerl and use BerryBrew to manage the perls on Windows, in this case I really want to *also* run perl on Linux on Windows!